# Unable search names which contain three 7s in random order by AWK/Python/Bash

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk

I need to find names which contain three number 7 in the random order.

**My attempt**

We need to find first names which do not contain seven

```
ls | grep [^7]
```

Then, we could remove these matches from the whole space

```
ls [remove] ls | grep [^7]
```

The problem in my pseudo-code starts to repeat itself quickly.

**How can you find the names which contain three 7s in the random order by AWK/Python/Bash?**

**[edit]**
The name can contain any number of letters and it contains words of three 7s.

Comment: Can you give some example filenames - it'll help clarify which should match and which shouldn't.

Comment: @Andy: Examples of filenames which should be matched are d41d8Zcd978fABe98009978ecf8427e, 7d41d8CoA00b204e7980U0998ecf8427e and 77d41d8CD98f00204E9800998Ecf8427e

Comment: @Andy: Examples of filenames which should not be matched are d41d8cd98f00b2049800998eCf842e, d41d8cd98F00b204e9800998ecf8427e and 77d41d8cd98f00b204E79800998ecf8427e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
printf '%s\n' *|awk -F7 NF==4
```

Comment: Neat solution using awk but replace the printf with an 'ls -1' or simply an 'ls' (which defaults to -1 if the output is a pipe).

Comment: No, ls is an external command (an expensive unnecessary fork) that is not needed in this case. On most modern shells printf is a builtin command so it's faster.

Comment: "Faster"? With 2 files I see 0.007s using ls vs. 0.004s with printf. Subtract a smidgeon as my timings needed an extra 'sh' to capture the glob time. With 1000 files the times are 0.010 vs. 0.009. With 10000 it's 0.031 vs 0.057 (printf slower) and "Argument list too long" with * on 100,000 files.

Comment: So while it is faster for the common case (few directories have >2000 files), it fails for some cases, and that failure bothers me more than the performance. Also, I just realized that ls should be 'ls -f' since  the OP didn't care about sorted order.

Comment: Arguably, anyone who has a Unix system running where 'ls' ISN'T cached in the VM is probably on a system that isn't doing anything. While the 'ls' fork won't be "free", when cached, it will most certainly be damn cheap.

Comment: Actually you cannot get "argument list too long with builtin commands,
so only ls could eventually break (assuming printf is a builtin and not external command, as already pointed out).

Comment: While I agree that in most cases the performance benefit will be insignificant, 
I don't see how ls could be better in this case.

Comment: @Masi,
%s is a character escape sequence which converts an argument to a string copies it to the standard output. -F7 sets the awk input field separator FS to the string/digit 7, NF == 6 means match only records that have exactly four fields, NF is number of fields (to be continued...)

Comment: i.e. the records that contain exactly three occurrences of the digit 7.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. 'which printf' gives me /usr/bin/printf for both bash and tcsh. That's why I get "Argument list too long". I did, after all, test my timing numbers

Comment: @dalke,
you should use type printf to verify, not which.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about type. Why does 'which cd' report cd is a built-in command and not printf? I did my timing tests with two bash scripts, 'time x1.sh' 'time x2.sh' being 'printf "%s\n" * > /dev/null' and 'ls > /dev/null' and I got Arg list too long. Why? Can you do better timings?

Comment: You get the Arg list too long error when you exceed the ARG_MAX system variable limit. This is on SunOS 5.8 machine with bash 2.03.0(1):

bash-2.03$ getconf ARG_MAX
1048320
bash-2.03$ printf '%s ' * | perl -nle'print length'
1083857

(continues ...)

Comment: ls will fail when you pass aruments (to filter based on a pattern, for example):

<pre>bash-2.03$ time ls * >&-
bash: /usr/bin/ls: Arg list too long

real    0m1.103s
user    0m0.890s
sys     0m0.370s
bash-2.03$ time printf '%s ' * >&-

real    0m1.211s
user    0m1.120s
sys     0m0.090s
</pre>

Comment: A builtin printf will not fail.

Comment: This is without arguments:

bash-2.03$ time ls >&-

real    0m1.581s
user    0m1.100s
sys     0m0.430s
bash-2.03$ time printf '%s' * >&-

real    0m1.267s
user    0m1.130s
sys     0m0.130s

Comment: Your time printf does not work to measure the glob time because globbing is done by the shell, which passes the argv to time, which forwards the argv to printf. The globbing there occurs *before* time starts, so the results aren't comparable. That's why I had to make a shell script to do the timings

Comment: So:

bash-2.03$ time bash -c 'ls  >&-'

real    0m1.583s
user    0m1.120s
sys     0m0.410s
bash-2.03$ time bash -c 'printf "%s\n" * >&-'

real    0m1.474s
user    0m1.210s
sys     0m0.260s

Comment: % time bash -c 'printf "%s\n" * >&-' :: Segmentation fault  :: 0.154u 1.833s 0:08.45 23.4%  :: 0+0k 9283+0io 0pf+0w :: % ls -f | wc -l :: 399714

Comment: Reading your posts I realize that probably I was not clear, evry builtin command is faster and more efficient than an external command because there is no need so start a sub shell. My point was about how many times you execute a command and not about extreme cases with 399714 files (continues...)

Comment: I believe this example illustrates what I was talking about:

time bash -c 'for c in {1..1000};do ls >/dev/null;done'

real    0m15.307s
user    0m33.299s
sys     0m10.276s

time bash -c 'for c in {1..1000};do printf '%s\n' * >/dev/null;done'

real    0m0.537s
user    0m0.265s
sys     0m0.234s

Comment: My timings agree with you: printf is faster than ls for small directories.  Once there are ~1000 files, my tests show ls as being faster. Perhaps due to poor malloc/string use? And printf fails for extreme cases. While slightly slower, I prefer 'ls -1f' as it doesn't break and it's easily understood

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand the part about "random order". How do you differentiate between the "order" when it's the same token that repeats? Is "a7b7" different from "c7d7" in the order of the 7s?

Anyway, this ought to work:

```
 ls *7*7*7*
```

It just let's the shell solve the problem, but maybe I didn't understand properly.

EDIT: The above is wrong, it includes cases with more than four 7s which is not wanted. Assuming this is bash, and extended globbing is enabled, this works:

```
ls *([^7])7*([^7])7*([^7])7*([^7])
```

This reads as "zero or more characters which are not sevens, followed by a seven, followed by zero or more characters that are not sevens", and so on. It's important to understand that the asterisk is a *prefix* operator here, operating on the expression `([^7])` which means "any character except 7".

Comment: Your command does not work. I mean that the filename can contain any number of letters and figures, and you need to find the words of three 7s.

Comment: Aah, thanks, that clarifies it. I knew there was something I was missing. :) I'll edit.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you want to find files that contain exactly three 7's, but no more.  Using gnu grep with the extends regexp switch (`-E`):

```
ls | grep -E '^([^7]*7){3}[^7]*$'
```

Should do the trick.

Basically that matches 3 occurrences of "not 7 followed by a 7", then a bunch of "not 7" across the whole string (the ^ and $ at the beginning and end of the pattern respectively).

Comment: It worked on my hosts Linux box.  Tested it by echoing some text strings and all seemed ok...  Perhaps the regexp isn't understood by the version of grep you are using?

Answer (score 2):

A Perl solution:

```
$ ls | perl -ne 'print if (tr/7/7/ == 3)'
3777
4777
5777
6777
7077
7177
7277
7377
7477
7577
7677
...
```

(I happen to have a directory with 4-digit numbers.  1777 and 2777 don't exist. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or instead of doing it in a single grep, use one grep to find files with 3-or-more 7s and another to filter out 4-or-more 7s.

```
ls -f | egrep '7.*7.*7' | grep -v '7.*7.*7.*7'
```

You could move some of the work into the shell glob with the shorter

```
ls -f *7*7*7* | grep -v '7.*7.*7.*7'
```

though if there are a large number of files which match that pattern then the latter won't work because of built-in limits to the glob size.

The '-f' in the 'ls' is to prevent 'ls' from sorting the results. If there is a huge number of files in the directory then the sort time can be quite noticeable.

This two-step filter process is, I think, more understandable than using the [^7] patterns.

Also, here's the solution as a Python script, since you asked for that as an option.

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.count("7") == 4:
        print filename
```

This will handle a few cases that the shell commands won't, like (evil) filenames which contain a newline character. Though even here the output in that case would likely still be wrong, or at least unprepared for by downstream programs.

Comment: Indeed. I needed a leading "*" and trailing "*". My test set for that case was too limited (only '777' and '7777'). Fixed. Thanks!